# How would I import YouTube Likes and Dislikes and a ratio from YouTube onto Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, youtube, google-sheets-formula

What would be the correct `xpath` to get  YouTube likes and dislikes from a video?

Comment: This is much too broad of a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### TITLE:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","//*[@id='eow-title']")
```

or:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(A12), 500, 1),
 "where Col1 contains '/title'", 0), ">(.+)<")
```

[image]

#### VIEWS:

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo",
 "//*[contains(@class, 'watch-view-count')]"),0)," view(s)?",""))
```

#### DURATION:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content"),"PT|S",""),"M",":")
```

#### LIKES:

```
=IF(ISNA(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-like-button')])[1]"))=TRUE,0,
         IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-like-button')])[1]"))
```

#### DISLIKES:

```
=IF(ISNA(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-dislike-button')])[1]"))=TRUE,0,
         IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-dislike-button')])[1]"))
```

#### UPLOADED:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo",
 "//*[contains(@class, 'watch-time-text')]"),"((Uploaded)|(Published)|(Streamed live)) on ","")
```

#### SUBSCRIPTIONS:

```
=IFERROR(MID(QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/channel/"&A1,
 "//div[@class='primary-header-actions']"), "select Col1"), 31, 20), )
```

[image: 6]

#### CHANNEL NAME:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7_gcs09iThXybpVgjHZ_7g","list",1),1,1)
```

#### CHANNEL ID:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 IMPORTDATA(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rckrnYw5sOA), 3000, 1), """", ""),
 "where Col1 contains '<meta itemprop=channelId content='"),
 "<meta itemprop=channelId content=|>", ""))
```

---

---

---

## UPDATE:

### channel name (07/07/2021):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A4)), 
 "where Col1 contains '\x22channelName\x22:\x22'", 0), ":\\x22(.+)\\x22$")
```

### video title (08/08/2021)

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 
 "where Col1 starts with 'title:""'", 0), """(.*)""")
```

[image]

### duration (21/04/2022)

```
=TEXT(1*REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(B1)), 
 "where Col1 contains 'approxDurationMs' limit 1", ), 
 "\d+")/3600000/24, "mm:ss")
```

[image]

### channel views (07/06/2022)

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*")), 
 "where Col1 contains '"&CHAR(10)&"Creators'", ), 
 ".x22text.x22:.x22(.+).x22,.x22bold.x22")
```

[image]

### video views (01/09/2022)

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)); 
 "where Col1 starts with 'viewCount'"; ); "\d+")*1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've found a much simpler solution though (can't post it, since the question is closed, so feel free to reuse it): `=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=",A12,"&format=xml"), "//title")`

Comment: Unfortunately duration stopped working...

Comment: @BartoszKP answer updated

Comment: The formula for views doesn't work I get this error message - Error, Imported content is empty.

Comment: @RazmikBadalyan answer updated