# Google Sheets YouTube Link and Name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How would I make it so when I paste a channel's YouTube link, I would also be able to get the channel name to generate?

so A1 would have Link and B1 would have the channel Name?

Comment: Try this `=IMPORTXML(A1, "//h1")`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IMPORTXML(C3,"//*[@id='eow-title']")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: @Nicodemuz https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064665/5632629