# xpath extract YouTube video name?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to extract data from the following h1 tag using Google Sheets `=IMPORTXML()` Function?

HTML tag:

```
<h1 class="title style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer"><yt-formatted-string force-default-style="" class="style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer">XPath query, IMPORTXML &amp; Google Sheets - Advanced Tutorial</yt-formatted-string></h1>
```

Result:

```
XPath query, IMPORTXML & Google Sheets - Advanced Tutorial
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is straightforward, first the url of your xml, then your xpath. Be careful with single and double quotes.

```
=IMPORTXML("link to your xml file or webpage";"//h1")
```

or to be more specific :

```
=IMPORTXML("link to your xml file or webpage";"//h1[@class='title style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer']")
```

EDIT : And to get what you need :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZ44kAeiOo";"//span[@class='watch-title']")
```

[image: YT Title]

Comment: Not work for, try to extract information from this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZ44kAeiOo

Comment: OK. Post is edited with an appropriate solution.

Comment: Can you explain why you used it class='watch-title' i didn't find this class in HTML code?

Comment: When you parse the page, the code is a bit different from the one you see in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","//*[@id='eow-title']")
```

**more @: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064665/5632629**