# xpath to YouTube Subscribers is not working

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, xpath-2.0

I am working on a sheet to get the Subscriber Count of a Youtube Channel. The problem is the old paths are not working anymore and the new one does not seem to return anything.

Here is what I have tried:

`"http://www.youtube.com/weargenius","//*[@id=\"c4-primary-header-contents\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/span[1]"`

`=IMPORTXML(I4,"//yt-formatted-string")`

`=IMPORTXML(I4,"//div[@class='style-scope ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer']")`

`=VALUE(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1,”//div[@class=’primary-header-actions’]”),1,1),”(Unsubscribe)([0-9kmKM.]+)”),1,2)),”([0-9,.]+)([km]?)”),,1) * SWITCH(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1,”//div[@class=’primary-header-actions’]”),1,1),”(Unsubscribe)([0-9kmKM.]+)”),1,2)),”([0-9,.]+)([km]?)”),,2),”k”,1000,”m”,1000000,1))`

and many more solutions that did not work.
What I would like to accomplish is that we can get the subscriber account using google sheets from youtube profile page.

Comment: I4 is the link to any channel, fyi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
=IMPORTXML(I4;"//span[contains(@class,'subscriber')]")
```

[image: YtbSubs]

Comment: Worked! Thank you!!

Comment: Replace ";" with ","  since I'm based in Europe. EDIT : Nice !

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFERROR(MID(QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/channel/"&A1,
 "//div[@class='primary-header-actions']"), "select Col1"), 31, 20), )
```

[image: 0]

```
=IFERROR(MID(QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCH58d6dGp6b0hisvkCh7sNg",
 "//div[@class='primary-header-actions']"), "select Col1"), 31, 20), )
```

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064665/5632629**