# How can you use IMPORTXML to get a YouTube Thumbnail from the XML feed?

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, xml-parsing, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to populate a Google Sheet with a table that contains the 10 most recent YouTube videos from a channel along with the video title, video URL, date, description, and thumbnail image.

When I try to use IMPORTXML on the Google Sheet, I get an error that "Imported content is empty":

[image: screenshot of Google Sheets error]

Here's the formula in the field:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCmGSJVG3mCRXVOP4yZrU1Dw","/feed/entry[1]/media:group/media:thumbnail/@url")
```

I've tried testing the xpath on a few online [testers](https://www.easycodeforall.com/generate-xpath.html), and they seem to return the URL, but it doesn't work in Google Sheets.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064665/5632629

Comment: Thanks for that link. It looks like that page is scraping the page for individual YouTube videos. Each channel has an XML feed that has all of the videos from a channel (ie. https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=[INSERT CHANNEL ID]), so I'm trying to pull the video thumbnail off this XML feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is a problem with namespaces.
See i.e. [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241062/3710053)

In your case the XPath could be:

```
/*[local-name()='feed']/*[local-name()='entry'][1]/*[local-name()='group']/*[local-name()='thumbnail']/@url
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I'll have to do more reading about namespaces to better understand it.