# How would I import YouTube video views into google sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, web-scraping, youtube, regex-replace

I have a list of videos for which I want to easily see the number of views. Is there a way to do that with REGEXREPLACE, or some other way?

Comment: Hi, @player0 that solution doesn't work. I got this error message - Imported content is empty.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064665/5632629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)); 
 "where Col1 starts with 'viewCount'"; ); "\d+")*1
```

[image]